# If $\vec F=\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ then $\exists$ is no $\vec G ∶ \mathbb{R}^3 ⧵ {0} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vec F = curl \,\vec G$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem, curl

If $\vec F=\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ then show that $\textrm{div} \vec F = 0$ but $\exists$ is no $\vec G ∶ \mathbb{R}^3 ⧵ {(0,0,0)} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vec F = \textrm{curl} \,\vec G$.

I can show that $\textrm{div} \vec F = 0$. I know that if $\textrm{div} \vec\, F = 0$ then there exists a vector $\vec G$ such that $\vec F = \textrm{curl}\, \vec G$.

What is happening here?

Please explain in details why $\vec F \neq \textrm{curl} \,\vec G$ here.

**Edit: Consider $\vec F:S\to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vec F=\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ and $S$ is the unit sphere centred at origin.**

Then outward drawn normal $\hat n$ to S is $\hat n=\vec r$ (since $|\vec r|=1$)

Then $$\int\int_S\vec F.\hat n ds=\int\int_S \frac{1}{r}dS=\int\int_SdS=4\pi.$$

But if $\vec F = \textrm{curl}\, \vec G$, then by using Stokes' theorem, we have
$$\int\int_S\vec F.\hat n ds=\int\int_S(\textrm{curl} \,\vec G).\hat n ds=\int_C \vec G.d\vec r$$.

Is my way of approach correct? How to find the last integral?

Comment: It is false that $\operatorname{div}\vec F=0 \implies \vec F = \operatorname{curl}\vec G$. This is a counterexample.

Comment: Please show that $div\,\vec F=0\rlap{\quad\not}\implies  \vec F = \operatorname{curl}\vec G
$ for this problem

Comment: @azif00 I have edited..please correct, if any error. Please complete the argument.

Comment: I recommend you to review the condition of the Stokes' theorem. There is something icky about `C` here.

Comment: @Abastro Yes I understand your point. I thought about that and not able to resolve the issue. What modifications needed here?

Comment: @user1942348 Notably, identify what are the domain of integrals. What is surface $S$? How about curve $C$?

Comment: S is the surface of the unit sphere, The problem arises with C. As the sphere is a closed, how to find C? I think no such C exists

Comment: Yep, now the flaw of the current logic is located. I believe you have learned about 2 kinds of stokes theorem, one for surface with boundary, and one for closed surface.

Comment: @Abastro Thanks. Would you kindly write the solution then in Answer Your Question style?